# OWASP CSRFGuard JavaScript was included from within an unauthorized domain! How to overcome this issue in cypress

Tags: cypress

In cypress automation,
when i try to launch the website.
`It thrown this error OWASP CSRFGuard JavaScript was included from within an unauthorized domain!`
I am kind of blocked due to this issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeVX0.png)

I need a solution to bypass this issue in cypress

Comment: In TIBCO JasperReports® Server v6.3.0 CSRF protection changed, and there is a known defect that can impact reverse-proxy setups. this link might be helpful https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/owasp-csrfguard-javascript-was-included-within-unauthorized-domain